# Fetching data from two file and changing it to another file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to fetch the following details from a file and merge it to the source file without altering the source file details. In short I would like to change a specify string in the source file from two different id files retaining the source file intact. I tried using for loop in python but i couldn't get what I wanted a help in this would be great.

Example:

`id.txt` & `list.txt` are two files which contain the id

1. id.txt

```
SEQ111000_S1
SEQ111001_S2
SEQ111002_S3
```

2. list.txt

```
/hover/covid/Reg-SEQ-111000
/hover/covid/Reg-SEQ-111001
/hover/covid/Reg-SEQ-111002
```

3. Source file

```
>SEQ111000_S1
ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAGTGCACTCACGCAGTATAATTAATAACTAATTACTGTCGTTGACAGGACACGAGTAACTCGTCTATCTTCTGCAGGCTGCTTACGGTTTCGTCCGTTTTGCAGCCGATCATCAGCACATCTAGGTTTTGTCCGGGTGTGACCGAAAGGTAAGATGGAGAGCCTTGTCCCTGGTTTCAACGAGAAAACACACGTCCAACTCAGTTTGCCTGTTTTACAGGTTCGCGACGTGCTCGTACGTGGCTTTGGAGACTCCGTGGAGGAGGTCTTATCAGAGGCACGTCAACATCTTAAAGATGGCACTTGTGGCTTAGTAGAAGTTGAAAAAGGCGTTTTGCCTCAACTTGAACAGCCCTATGTGTTCATCAAACGTTCGGATGCTCGAACTGCACCTCATGGTCATGTTATGGTTGAGCTGGTAGCAGAACTCGAAGGCATTCAGTACGGTCGTAGTGGTGAGACACTTGGTGTCCTTGTCCCTCATGTGGGCGAAATACCAGTGGCTTACCGCAAGGTTCTTCTTCGTAAGAACGGTAATAAAGGAGCTGGTGGCCATAGTTACGGCGCCGATCTAAAGTCATTTGACTTAGGCGACGAGCTTGGCACTGATCCTTATGAAGATTTTCAAGAAAACTGGAACACTAAACATAGCAGTGGTGTTACCCGTGAACTCATGCGTGAGCTTAACGGAGGGGCATACACTCGCTATGTCGATAACAACTTCTGTGGCCCTGATG
>SEQ111001_S2
ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAGTGCACTCACGCAGTATAATTAATAACTAATTACTGTCGTTGACAGGACACGAGTAACTCGTCTATCTTCTGCAGGCTGCTTACGGTTTCGTCCGTTTTGCAGCCGATCATCAGCACATCTAGGTTTTGTCCGGGTGTGACCGAAAGGTAAGATGGAGAGCCTTGTCCCTGGTTTCAACGAGAAAACACACGTCCAACTCAGTTTGCCTGTTTTACAGGTTCGCGACGTGCTCGTACGTGGCTTTGGAGACTCCGTGGAGGAGGTCTTATCAGAGGCACGTCAACATCTTAAAGATGGCACTTGTGGCTTAGTAGAAGTTGAAAAAGGCGTTTTGCCTCAACTTGAACAGCCCTATGTGTTCATCAAACGTTCGGATGCTCGAACTGCACCTCATGGTCATGTTATGGTTGAGCTGGTAGCAGAACTCGAAGGCATTCAGTACGGTCGTAGTGGTGAGACACTTGGTGTCCTTGTCCCTCATGTGGGCGAAATACCAGTGGCTTACCGCAAGGTTCTTCTTCGTAAGAACGGTAATAAAGGAGCTGGTGGCCATAGTTACGGCGCCGATCTAAAGTCATTTGACTTAGGCGACGAGCTTGGCACTGATCCTTATGAAGATTTTCAAGAAAACTGGAACACTAAACATAGCAGTGGTGTTACCCGTGAACTCATGCGTGAGCTTAACGGAGGGGCATACACTCGCTATGTCGATAACAACTTCTGTGGCCCTGATG
>SEQ111003_S3
ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAGTGCACTCACGCAGTATAATTAATAACTAATTACTGTCGTTGACAGGACACGAGTAACTCGTCTATCTTCTGCAGGCTGCTTACGGTTTCGTCCGTTTTGCAGCCGATCATCAGCACATCTAGGTTTTGTCCGGGTGTGACCGAAAGGTAAGATGGAGAGCCTTGTCCCTGGTTTCAACGAGAAAACACACGTCCAACTCAGTTTGCCTGTTTTACAGGTTCGCGACGTGCTCGTACGTGGCTTTGGAGACTCCGTGGAGGAGGTCTTATCAGAGGCACGTCAACATCTTAAAGATGGCACTTGTGGCTTAGTAGAAGTTGAAAAAGGCGTTTTGCCTCAACTTGAACAGCCCTATGTGTTCATCAAACGTTCGGATGCTCGAACTGCACCTCATGGTCATGTTATGGTTGAGCTGGTAGCAGAACTCGAAGGCATTCAGTACGGTCGTAGTGGTGAGACACTTGGTGTCCTTGTCCCTCATGTGGGCGAAATACCAGTGGCTTACCGCAAGGTTCTTCTTCGTAAGAACGGTAATAAAGGAGCTGGTGGCCATAGTTACGGCGCCGATCTAAAGTCATTTGACTTAGGCGACGAGCTTGGCACTGATCCTTATGAAGATTTTCAAGAAAACTGGAACACTAAACATAGCAGTGGTGTTACCCGTGAACTCATGCGTGAGCTTAACGGAGGGGCATACACTCGCTATGTCGATAACAACTTCTGTGGCCCTGATG
```

The python code which i tried:

```
import os

x1 = []
y1 = []


# Reading data from id.txt file 
with open("id.txt", "r") as f_in:
    data = f_in.read()
    d1 = data.split("\n")
    d2 = d1.remove('')
    d2 = d1.append(x1)

# Reading data from list.txt 
with open("list.txt", "r") as g_in:
    data = g_in.read()
    d1 = data.split(",")
    d2 = d1.remove('')
    d2 = d1.append(y1)

for i in range(x1):
 for j in range(y1):
   os.system("sed 's|{i}|{j}/g' source.log > full-out.log")
```

What i am trying to get is just replacing the `SEQ111000_S1` to `/hover/covid/Reg-SEQ-111001` by matching just number from both the file in "id.txt" & "list.txt" [i.e 111000 & 111001] keeping the source file data intact.

```
/hover/covid/Reg-SEQ-111001
ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAGTGCACTCACGCAGTATAATTAATAACTAATTACTGTCGTTGACAGGACACGAGTAACTCGTCTATCTTCTGCAGGCTGCTTACGGTTTCGTCCGTTTTGCAGCCGATCATCAGCACATCTAGGTTTTGTCCGGGTGTGACCGAAAGGTAAGATGGAGAGCCTTGTCCCTGGTTTCAACGAGAAAACACACGTCCAACTCAGTTTGCCTGTTTTACAGGTTCGCGACGTGCTCGTACGTGGCTTTGGAGACTCCGTGGAGGAGGTCTTATCAGAGGCACGTCAACATCTTAAAGATGGCACTTGTGGCTTAGTAGAAGTTGAAAAAGGCGTTTTGCCTCAACTTGAACAGCCCTATGTGTTCATCAAACGTTCGGATGCTCGAACTGCACCTCATGGTCATGTTATGGTTGAGCTGGTAGCAGAACTCGAAGGCATTCAGTACGGTCGTAGTGGTGAGACACTTGGTGTCCTTGTCCCTCATGTGGGCGAAATACCAGTGGCTTACCGCAAGGTTCTTCTTCGTAAGAACGGTAATAAAGGAGCTGGTGGCCATAGTTACGGCGCCGATCTAAAGTCATTTGACTTAGGCGACGAGCTTGGCACTGATCCTTATGAAGATTTTCAAGAAAACTGGAACACTAAACATAGCAGTGGTGTTACCCGTGAACTCATGCGTGAGCTTAACGGAGGGGCATACACTCGCTATGTCGATAACAACTTCTGTGGCCCTGATG
/hover/covid/Reg-SEQ-111002
ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAGTGCACTCACGCAGTATAATTAATAACTAATTACTGTCGTTGACAGGACACGAGTAACTCGTCTATCTTCTGCAGGCTGCTTACGGTTTCGTCCGTTTTGCAGCCGATCATCAGCACATCTAGGTTTTGTCCGGGTGTGACCGAAAGGTAAGATGGAGAGCCTTGTCCCTGGTTTCAACGAGAAAACACACGTCCAACTCAGTTTGCCTGTTTTACAGGTTCGCGACGTGCTCGTACGTGGCTTTGGAGACTCCGTGGAGGAGGTCTTATCAGAGGCACGTCAACATCTTAAAGATGGCACTTGTGGCTTAGTAGAAGTTGAAAAAGGCGTTTTGCCTCAACTTGAACAGCCCTATGTGTTCATCAAACGTTCGGATGCTCGAACTGCACCTCATGGTCATGTTATGGTTGAGCTGGTAGCAGAACTCGAAGGCATTCAGTACGGTCGTAGTGGTGAGACACTTGGTGTCCTTGTCCCTCATGTGGGCGAAATACCAGTGGCTTACCGCAAGGTTCTTCTTCGTAAGAACGGTAATAAAGGAGCTGGTGGCCATAGTTACGGCGCCGATCTAAAGTCATTTGACTTAGGCGACGAGCTTGGCACTGATCCTTATGAAGATTTTCAAGAAAACTGGAACACTAAACATAGCAGTGGTGTTACCCGTGAACTCATGCGTGAGCTTAACGGAGGGGCATACACTCGCTATGTCGATAACAACTTCTGTGGCCCTGATG
/hover/covid/Reg-SEQ-111003
ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAACGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAGTGCACTCACGCAGTATAATTAATAACTAATTACTGTCGTTGACAGGACACGAGTAACTCGTCTATCTTCTGCAGGCTGCTTACGGTTTCGTCCGTTTTGCAGCCGATCATCAGCACATCTAGGTTTTGTCCGGGTGTGACCGAAAGGTAAGATGGAGAGCCTTGTCCCTGGTTTCAACGAGAAAACACACGTCCAACTCAGTTTGCCTGTTTTACAGGTTCGCGACGTGCTCGTACGTGGCTTTGGAGACTCCGTGGAGGAGGTCTTATCAGAGGCACGTCAACATCTTAAAGATGGCACTTGTGGCTTAGTAGAAGTTGAAAAAGGCGTTTTGCCTCAACTTGAACAGCCCTATGTGTTCATCAAACGTTCGGATGCTCGAACTGCACCTCATGGTCATGTTATGGTTGAGCTGGTAGCAGAACTCGAAGGCATTCAGTACGGTCGTAGTGGTGAGACACTTGGTGTCCTTGTCCCTCATGTGGGCGAAATACCAGTGGCTTACCGCAAGGTTCTTCTTCGTAAGAACGGTAATAAAGGAGCTGGTGGCCATAGTTACGGCGCCGATCTAAAGTCATTTGACTTAGGCGACGAGCTTGGCACTGATCCTTATGAAGATTTTCAAGAAAACTGGAACACTAAACATAGCAGTGGTGTTACCCGTGAACTCATGCGTGAGCTTAACGGAGGGGCATACACTCGCTATGTCGATAACAACTTCTGTGGCCCTGATG
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Being able to describe how your code fails to meet your expectations is the first step in fixing your code.

Comment: If you're processing FASTA files, you might want to make use of a library for it instead of rolling your own code.

Comment: @barmar its the fasta file only but changing the header to full defined tag from seq11 is what i needed help in.

Comment: `d2 = d1.append(x1)` makes no sense. `append()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: `x1` and `y1` are empty lists, why are you looping over them?

Comment: @barmar with open("id.txt", "r") as f_in:
    data = f_in.read()
    d1 = data.split("\n")
    d2 = d1.remove('')
    d2 = d1.append(x1) here i trying to append the id into tuple. append does load the id into the x1 variable.

Comment: How do you change a file and leave it "intact"?

Comment: The syntax is `x1.append(d2)`

Comment: But then `x1` will just contain one element. If you want `x1` to be the list of lines, just use `x1 = d2`.

Comment: @JonSG i am just trying to change the string tag with "SEQ111001" to the "/hover/covid/Reg-SEQ-111001" leaving the rest of the data intact.

Comment: Why are you splitting `list.txt` using `,`? There are no commas in the sample file you showed.

Comment: Each time through the loop you're just replacing one of the strings from the original source file. You're not combining all the replacements.

Comment: @barmar i think i missed while typing it

/hover/covid/Reg-SEQ-111000,
/hover/covid/Reg-SEQ-111001,
/hover/covid/Reg-SEQ-111002

Comment: You shouldn't use nested loops. You should loop over the two lists in parallel: `for i, j in zip(x1, y1):`

Comment: There are so many problems in your code, you don't seem to understand some of the basics.

Comment: @barmar i am just learning python so i might be bit cranky with coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your append syntax is wrong. Also, using `append()` will nest the lines inside the lists, which you don't need to do. Just use the lists directly.

`remove()` doesn't return the modified list, it modifies the list in place. It also only removes one match. Use a list comprehension to loop over the list an skip all the empty strings.

Use `zip()` to iterate over the two lists in parallel.

There's no need to use `sed`, you can do the replacements in Python itself.

```
with open("id.txt") as f:
    x1 = f.read().split("\n")
    x1 = [x for x in x1 if x != '']

with open("list.txt") as f:
    y1 = f.read().split(",")
    y1 = [y for y in y1 if y != '']

with open("source.log") as log_in, open("full-out.log", "w") as log_out:
    for line in log_in:
        for old, new in zip(x1, y1):
            if old in line:
                line = line.replace(old, new)
                break
        log_out.write(line)
```